# Delete duplicated rows from database

Tags: sql, database

I need to delete duplicated rows from database. Can i do it with simple sql query? If not, please, show me some quick algorythm to do it.

Example:

```
id| field_one | field_two |
1 | 0000000   | 11111111  |
2 | 2222222   | 33333333  |
3 | 2222222   | 33333333  |
4 | 4444444   | 55555555  |
```

I need to delete row with id 2 (or 3, no matter, they are equal, but not both).
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
delete from the_table where id in
   (select max(id) from the_table
      group by field_one, field_two
      having count(*) > 1)
```

As pointed out in the comments, this will not work if a row appears three times. You can run this (heavy) query repeatedly until it stops deleting stuff, or wait for a better answer...

Comment: +1 - Was in the middle of posting exactly the same answer. Speed counts!

Comment: And if you have the same row three times?

Comment: @Parkyprg Thank god i have not :) But for that sake of knowledge i would be glad if someone show the solution with N duplicates.

Comment: I'm getting this error: ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'xyz' for update in FROM clause

Answer (score 3):

First select all the distinct rows and then delete the other ones:

```
DELETE FROM MyTable 
WHERE id NOT IN
      (
        SELECT MAX(id) FROM MyTable
        GROUP BY field_one, field_two
      )
```

Comment: +1. That would work with rows duplicated more than once. It could be quite slow though, if most rows are not duplicated. I suppose it is good to have both queries in your arsenal and chose according to the situation at hand.

Comment: Another useful approach when there are many duplicates could be to copy the "good" rows into a working/staging table, and then truncate the old one. That avoids fragmentation.

Answer (score 2):

```
set rowcount 1 
delete userTbl1 from userTbl1 a1 where (select count(UName) from userTbl1 a2 where a2.UName =a1.UName)>1
while @@rowcount > 0 
delete userTbl1 from userTbl1 a1 where (select count(UName) from userTbl1 a2 where a2.UName =a1.UName)>1
set rowcount 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Thilo's answer is a useful one, it just makes what you want. Anyway if you have many lines it could take up much time as the algorithm has a square complexity. If I were the person who asked, I would choose Thilo's answer as best answer, anyway I just want to give you another option: if you have many lines then another possibility is:

**create a new table, set up a UNIQUE INDEX for the column combination: (field_one, field_two) and copy the content of the first table into the new one. Then you delete the old one and rename the new one to the old table name.**

That's all.