# How to delete duplicated database records?

Tags: android, database

i have a list with some items.The use can save some of them in a database,as favorites.My problem is that i m getting duplicated records in the database if he try to add the same item two times in the favorites.How can i fix it?

i was thinking something like

```
ourDatabase.rawQuery("DELETE FROM "+DBHelper.DATABASE_TABLE+" WHERE"+DBHelper.NAME+" EQUALS "+DBHelper.NAME+");",null);
```

but it's not working.

This is my create Entry method

```
public void createEntry(String name, String dodes) {

         try {        
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(NAME, name);
            cv.put(DODES, dodes);

              //  ourDatabase.rawQuery("DELETE FROM "+DBHelper.DATABASE_TABLE+" WHERE "+DBHelper.NAME+" = "+DBHelper.NAME+");",null);
                ourDatabase.insert("DB", null, cv); 

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Exception in insert :", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: An approach could be to select distinct and delete everything not in the intersection all records and that set...I think.

Comment: my question is the same with this,but for android http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888606/delete-duplicated-rows-from-database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before inserting, check to see if an item with the same name already exists. If so, do an update instead of an insert.

```
Cursor crsr = null;
try
{
  crsr = ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT _id FROM "+DBHelper.DATABASE_TABLE
      +" WHERE "+DBHelper.NAME+"='"+name+"'", null);
}
catch ( Exception excp )
{
  crsr = null;
}
if ( (crsr == null) || (crsr.getCount() < 1) )
  // Insert item
else
  // Update item
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I m getting " sqlite return : error code = 1,msg = near ")":syntax error "

Comment: Sorry, I had copied your delete query and didn't edit it completely. It should work now.

Comment: Ok,thats fixed,but still my problem is that if i have an item e.x."item 1", and a second "item 2" im getting  sqlite return : error code = 1,msg = near "item":syntax error "

Comment: your way makes wrong in rawQuery and promts me to change name from string to string[]..

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is to ensure that the record is "unique".

You can do this inside the database by adding a "unique index".

We want something like

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_name ON some_table(name)
```

So something like this in code;

```
"CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_name ON "+
DBHelper.DATABASE_TABLE+
"("+DBHelper.NAME+")"
```

This means that if you try and insert a duplicate, you will get an error.

Therefore you'll also need to add code that checks whether the `name` already exists, before you try and do it.